Kalman Filter Update Step Covariance Form
I am trying to understand the update step in the Kalman Filter as expressed in covariance form.
Here is the notation I will use, so we are on the same page:
$x_{i+1}=A_ix_i+v_i$ where $v_i\sim N(0,Q_i)$ and $y_i=C_ix_i+w_i$ where $w_i\sim N(0,R_i)$. We also have $x_0\sim N(0,\Lambda_0)$.
I want to know how to prove the update equations in covariance form (I know how to do it in information form, this is relatively straightforward):
$\hat{\mu}_i=\hat{\mu}_{i|i-1}+K_iz_i$ and $\hat{\Lambda}_i=\hat{\Lambda}_{i|i-1}+K_i\Lambda_{z_i,z_i}K_i^\intercal$ where $z_i=y_i-C_i\hat{\mu}_{i|i-1}$ is the innovation and $K_i=\Lambda_{x_i,z_i}\Lambda_{z_i,z_i}^{-1}$ is the Kalman Gain.
And just to clarify, these means are all means of causal posteriors, i.e. $\mu_i$ is the mean of $p(x_i|x_1,\dots,x_{i-1},y_1,\dots,y_i)$ and $\mu_{i|i-1}$ is the mean of $p(x_i|x_1,\dots,x_{i-1},y_1,\dots,y_{i-1})$.

So what is the easiest way to prove this? I tried 1) converting from the information form update equation and 2) calculating those covariances in $K_i$ and simplifying, but I keep running into the inverse of the addition of matrices which seems hard to simplify.
For example, if I try to compute $\Lambda_{z_i,z_i}$ I end up with something like
$$\Lambda_{z_i,z_i}=C_i(\hat{\Lambda}_i-\hat{\mu}_i\hat{\mu}_i^\intercal)C_i+R_i$$
which simply does not seem ot have a nice inverse we can simplify when plugging into $K_i$. Any help would be appreciated!

Hi: I haven't heard of the terminology "covariance form" but I'm not claiming that it's not popular. There is so much literature and so many notations !!!!! I am more confident that most of the literature doesn't use $x_t$ as the state. But neither of those things matter. My guess is that you may be referring to the updating equations for the other formulation of the KF which is where are $x_i$ and $y_{i}$ are aligned rather than $x_i$ being one step ahead as it is in your formulation. That's just a guess but it could be possible.

To clarify, I am talking about the "correction" step in the "predict-correct" framework, which I believe this is common terminology. And when I say in covariance form, I just mean the update equations in terms of $(\mu,\Lambda)$ rather than $(J,h)$, which would be the information form (I also believe this is common terminology).

I've never heard of it so, unfortunately, I can't help because I don't even know what it is. I'm just curious where you've seen the terms "covariance form" and "information form" since you say that it's common terminology.

Hi Max: This provides a derivation. https://www.kalmanfilter.net/covUpdate.html Whether it's always called the covariance update formulation. I don't know. I have a feeling there is another name for it but maybe not. I hope it helps.

@mlofton: in the control systems community, the "covariance form" is known as the "what are you talking about, that's a plain old Kalman filter!" form.  In that same community, $x_k$ is the usual name for the state variable.  Both the "covariance form" and $x_k$ are in Kalman's original paper, so I think it's OK to use them.

Thanks Tim for the terminology lesson. I think there are terminology differences between fields but then also even differences within fields. So, it's probably a good idea when asking about the KF,  to have the two equations written down at a minimum so that one can do whatever mapping in their head that is needed. But the person asking this current question did that and I was still confused so it's not a full proof mechanism.

No, there aren't "nice" inverses when you're trying to go from the information form to the covariance form or back.
However, you can use the matrix inversion lemma to resolve your final update for $\Lambda_{z_i, z_i}$ into something that's at least sensible, even if it'll involve multiple terms.
See Optimal State Estimation, Kalman, $H_{\infty}$ and Nonlinear Approaches, Dan Simon, Wiley, 2006 for more information.
The information filter is a pretty commonly treated form of the Kalman filter (all the literature I've seen introduces the covariance form first, then derives the information form from it).  So there should be a rich source of material to draw from in finding all the various ways you can go from one to the other.
